# Separate tables for name and email addresses?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I've been fighting my initial decision since I've began work on my database.  I'm debating whether or not I need a separate table for email addresses.  My database looks like this:

```
people(id, first_name, last_name, email)
addresses(id, address, street, city, state, zip, latitude, longitude)
addresses_people(id, person_id, address_id)
phone_numbers(id, person_id, phone_number, type)
```

I figured I didn't need a separate table for email addresses as I only wanted one per person regardless if they have more.  The problem I'm seeming to have though is that some people will NOT have email addresses.  Very often I will be storing children in the people table.  Now it seems like it would be better design if I put the email addresses in a separate table to avoid the thousands of empty email fields I'll have.

It's a huge hassle to change this now as the app is already in production somewhat, but changing it now as opposed to a year or two from now would be exponentially easier.  Is it worth a day or two to change the emails to another table?

Comment: Then you're substituting thousands of empty text fields for thousands of empty foreign key fields.

Comment: What proportion of the fields would be empty?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: the foreign key might be on the `emails` tables side.

Comment: @StuartDunkeld about 30% I would say.

Comment: Yeah the foreign key would be on the emails side.  id, person_id, email so no empty fields

Comment: That would imply multiple email address support, which you said you weren't supporting.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment So basically if I'm not supporting multiple email addresses keep it in the same table because empty fields don't matter.  That seems to be the consensus.  Sounds good to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion you are over-engineering. Optional `email` field is fine. Actually having a separate table might introduce much bigger overhead.

The only reason for a separate table is to model 1-N relationship if you expect the user to have more than one e-mail.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  I like that answer :) saves me a lot of time.  Just a little follow up question.  What about my addresses_people table?  I recently realized that more than one person could have the same address.  For example the mother and father of a child I want stored as two different people, but they have the same address.  Is having the link table addresses_people a better way to go then having the same address for two different people?  This situation wouldn't happen often though.  Most of the time I would have one parent stored, but I want the option for both.

Comment: @Brian: actually if a person can live in only one place I would simply go for `address_id` foreign key in `people` table - no need for `addresses_people` join table. Besides very often address is simply part of the person record - but is kind of denormalized form.

Comment: That seems so obvious :) I don't know why I over thought it like that!

Comment: interesting so how do you let the user update emails? with a single table, user changes email, you send confirmation to both old and new emails, but the new email is used only after user confirms it

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no need to change it.  Having some fields in a row be empty is not a big deal most of the time.  In fact, it is common in most databases.  The design of the database should depend on the objects you are trying to model primarily and not be concerned with separating things into tables simply for storage reasons unless you have serious storage constraints or other extenuating circumstances.

See [Database design - empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751489/database-design-empty-fields) which also shed a lot of light on your question.